# executing touch with execvp in c

Tags: c, linux

I want to create a file in c by using execvp. the name of that file is in int1 variable. but it doesn't work.

```
int int1;
sscanf((char*) file_memory,"%d",&int1 );
char* arg_list[] = {
        "touch",
        "int1",
         NULL
        };
execvp ("touch",arg_list);
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is never an adequate problem description. Please describe exactly the input, the expected behavior and the actual behaviour of your program is. And you can start by checking whether `execvp` succeeds or not and if not then print the `errno`.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a file literally named `int1`, because you wrote a string literal. Variables are not expanded inside string literals. You need to fill in a string variable with the integer value.

```
int int1;
sscanf((char*) file_memory,"%d",&int1 );
char name[20];
snprintf(name, sizeof name, "%d", int1);
char *arg_list[] = {
    "touch",
    name,
    NULL,
};
execvp("touch", arg_list);
```